# Link to a View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm new at iOS so am learning..

I'm using interface builder and added an image using (Image View) and a button using (Button) and added a (View Controller) so I can link the image AND the button to it, I dragged and dropped the button to the View Controller that I just added but when I do the same to the image it doesn't work, can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImageView does not respond to taps by default. If you want a tap on the image to segue to the second controller, you need to create another button (instead of the ImageView) and set the background image to your image. Then connect the new button to the second controller.

There are many free iOS tutorials online. I suggest you follow some of those so you can get a feel for what each control can do. NatashaTheRobot.com and RayWenderlich.com have some free introductory tutorials.

Comment: I'll check the online now, but, when I create another button, it doest show to new picture name in the interface builder in the Attributes Inspector.. :/